# Handling DepCheck Missing Dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I have a couple questions on the results that DepCheck returns for "Missing Dependencies" (screenshot below)

- How do Node_Modules exist for most of these dependencies returned, even though they are not listed in package.json ? Some of these missing dependencies (Service worker dependencies, for example) are not breaking my app (to my knowledge)
- Is it correct that the fix for these is to simply "npm i" them one at a time?

[depcheck missing dependencies list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOD9x.png)

Thanks!